# Disable click on a table td but activate click on div a the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with 2 column (in the column there are x rows).
Now with a simple button and JS I can switch from column 1 and column 2, when column 1 is enabled column 2 is disabled and vice versa.

There is now a greyout layer on the disabled column with the property: pointer-event: none; that prevent input from the user (in the row there are buttons and inputbox that DOESN'T HAVE to be triggered when the column is disabled).

But now I have a problem, I have to enable the column also clicking on the greyout zone, not only with the button.
I tried with a div inside the row / column but it doesn't work properly.
When I add the div in the column and add the property: pointer-events: all; to the div all the inputbox and buttons were triggered by the pointer (not correct).

Do you have any idea? (I can also use Primefaces, tried with BlockUI but something doesn't work properly)

Here simple graphic example of what I want

[image]

Comment: I saw you other question about the CSS-shape in here. It was recently deleted. You can see the solution [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NEExdW) ... People are such sticklers about how questions are being asked. But it's probably for the greater good, to keep som structure in here. Don't let the down-votes discourage you, though. Keep coding, bro! And [this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) explains a bit about the triangle-shapes in my Codepen. It's a bit hacky. And if it was me, then I'd probably just use an image for it.

Comment: Really thank you man! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.right input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
  $('.left input[type="text"],.left button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('.left').addClass('distd');
})

$('.right input[type="text"]').on('blur', function() {
  $('.left input[type="text"],.left button').prop('disabled', false);
  $('.left').removeClass('distd');
})

$('.left input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
  $('.right input[type="text"],.right button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('.right').addClass('distd');
})

$('.left input[type="text"]').on('blur', function() {
  $('.right input[type="text"],.right button').prop('disabled', false);
  $('.right').removeClass('distd');
})
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black
}

td {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.distd {
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" /></td>
    <td class="right"><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td class="right">
      <input type="text" />
      <button>sample btn</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td class="right">
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td class="right">
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>sample btn</button>
```

Is that how you need it to be ???

-- Updated --

OVERLAY ADDED

Comment: Not like that but near.
I have to show a greyout layer on all the inputbox and buttons, not greyout one by one

Comment: Not yet, I need to show a greyout square on all the column (what I'm tring to do now is with a div with background-color grey and opacity 0.5)
But still problem with the pointer events

Comment: check again -- UPDATED --